# Is the journal's country important when choosing a journal for your article?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

I noticed that many journals' rankings include the country. And also, I found that some journals are called "International ...".

I start wondering if the country is important when choosing a journal to submit my paper?
If my university and I are in country A, can I still submit an article to journal from country B? Or only "International " journals available for me?

Comment: It's a trick of "salami slicers" to spread their papers around the globe.  First paper goes to a Canadian journal.  2nd paper (which is the first paper missing the first page and with one page added) goes to an Indian journal.  Cut off another page and append another, this 3rd paper goes to a Mexican journal.  It helps hide the fact that 1.5 papers-worth of material was published 10 times.  It's harder to spot unless you read ALL the journals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I start wondering if the country is important when choosing a journal to submit my paper? If my university and I are in country A, can I still submit an article to journal from country B? Or only "International " journals available for me?

For most journals, this will not be important.
For example, the British Ecological Society and Ecological Society of America both publish journals that are open to ecologists globally.
Sometimes, there are regional journals that only focus on specific regions.

Conversely, some journals like the [Canadian Field Naturalist](https://www.canadianfieldnaturalist.ca/index.php/cfn) historically have had geographic specific missions. For example, CFN describes (described? I'm having trouble finding this quote on their current homepage) itself as

> A peer-reviewed scientific journal publishing ecology, behaviour, taxonomy, conservation, and other topics relevant to Canadian natural history.

Hence, a paper on Australian species would not be relevant unless the paper tied back to Canada or Canadian species somehow.

More broadly, you can find this out by reading the "about", "author's instruction", or similar section  of the journal as well as reading recent articles (or at least skimming titles and abstracts).

**Edit:** Based upon a comment from Buffy, there are also journals that limit authors based upon their affiliation.
For example, *The Texas Journal of Science* is limited to work done in Texas or nearby areas **OR** done by Texas scientists anywhere (bold added by me):

> The geographic scope of manuscripts published in the Journal are generally limited to **work conducted by authors while at Texas institutions** or to work conducted in Texas or adjacent areas (surrounding states and Mexico) that has some direct relevance to Texas natural history (regardless of author’s institutional location).

Comment: Those are topic limitations, of course, not limitations on the nationality of authors.

Comment: @Buffy Thank you for your clarification. I appreciate thoughtful inputs on this site. I added an example that is only open to geographic scientists. (I went to grad school in Texas, hence I've heard of that journal).

Comment: Then you have things like the IBM Journal of Research and Development and the Bell System Technical Journal. While neither is published anymore (sadly), they only accepted manuscripts from within their respective companies.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can submit a paper to a journal published in a different country. Some journals require articles be in a specific language, but other than that there are no restrictions.

"International" could mean a lot of things, including that the journal has a business presence in several countries, or publishes in multiple languages. But it isn't a restriction on submissions.

Note that if a journal's readership is concentrated in some country, and you want to write, primarily, for people in that country, then such a journal may have some "importance" for you. But the world of scholarship is very international now.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to add that, at least in some disciplines, it seems to be somekind of scheme for founders of predatory journals to take the name of an established journal, put the word "international" in front of it, and then name their new predatory journal this way. (On the other hand, there are of course also serious journals with "international" in their name.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thanks for the comment about predatory journals. But wouldn't people massively know that some journals are predatory? I look at https://www.scimagojr.com/ ranking, and I utterly hope that a predatory journal would not be shown there...